# Complete convergence and almost sure convergence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_{n}$ be a sequence of independent random variables. Prove that $X_{n}$ converges to zero, almost everywhere (a.e.) if and only if for all $\epsilon >0$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } P(|X_{n}|>\epsilon)<\infty$.

This relates the complete convergence with the almost sure convergence but I need help to prove it, it might be a theorem...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** for both directions, use the Borel-Cantelli lemma with the independent events $A_{n,\varepsilon}:=\{|X_n|\gt \varepsilon\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried and I cannot solve it, help please!! Thanks!!

Comment: Could you write your attempt?